# Examples of PID's with finitely many maximal ideals

Tags: principal-ideal-domains

Do you know some examples of principal ideal domains which have finitely many maximal ideals? More generally, do you know how to build such domains? I don't look for fields and discrete valuation rings.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to construct a PID with finitely many maximal ideals.

1. Start with a PID $R$.
2. Pick finitely many $M_1, M_2, \dots , M_k$ maximal ideals of $R$, and call $S=R \setminus (M_1 \cup M_2 \cup \dots \cup M_k)$: this is a multiplicative subset of $R$.
3. $S^{-1}R$ is a PID (because it is a localization of a PID) whose maximal ideals are exactly $S^{-1}M_1, S^{-1}M_2, \dots  , S^{-1}M_k$.